# Convert lib + header file to DLL

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I have a library (lib file + .h header file). I like to turn it into a DLL so I can easiliy use it in VB6. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert static windows library to dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845183/convert-static-windows-library-to-dll)

Comment: What does the lib contain? Does it only contain import descriptors for some external DLL or does it contain actual code?

Answer (score 2):

Simply include the header file an a .def file in a new dll project and link it with the static lib.

The details of how to export symbols with a def file are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh(VS.80).aspx

Comment: On windows he may have to modify the header file to inform VC what symbols have to be exported from the DLL. so he may add some __declspec xxx around the functions in the header file.

Comment: You can use a .def file to force the export of functions without requiring the __declspec in the headers.  I recommend this because the poster does not require the header to both import and export.

Comment: Remember the def file contains the mangled names, so for C++ especially this will be a pain to maintain.

Comment: You are right about C++ name mangling, but maintaining the def file will be easy compared to the VB6 code calling the functions :-)