# JNA - calling methods upon C++ instance passed back from DLL

Tags: java, jna

Say I have a C++ DLL with a single exported method such as:

```
CustomerProcessor* getInstance();
```

i.e. it simply returns an instance of the class that actually contains the methods I need to call.

I know I can map the getInstance() method to a Class in Java using JNA (extending com.sun.jna.Library), store the returned CustomerProcessor instance in a com.sun.jna.Pointer.

Can I then somehow map this to the CustomerProcessor class so that I can call methods upon it (and if so, how)?

Comment: according to this question you cannot call C++ methods in JNA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556421/use-jni-instead-of-jna-to-call-native-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any arbitrary `type* function()` definition you can map the method using JNA as returning a `com.sun.jna.Pointer`, but you won't be able to invoke methods on a C++ object from JNA.

A simple workaround for this would be to write a C interface library that simply invokes the method on the objects for you...so if you have some member function `foo()` you could export a C method from your C++ code:

```
extern "C" void bar(type* var){
   var->foo();
}
```

Obviously this will add some work for you...but I suspect the overhead for switching to [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) would be about the same.

Comment: I've actually already gone down the route of writing a C++ wrapper, but was wondering if there was anyway to eliminate it.  Many thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) may facilitate doing what you ask.  It has some support for demangling and vtable access (required for calling *this methods).