# Java Native Access doesn't do C++, right?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, jna

I've found many references online (including some on stackoverflow) to JNA being used for C++ libraries, but nothing I can find in the JNA docs indicates that's possible. There doesn't seem to be any way to wrap a C++ class, in particular.

I need native access to use RTAudio, but all of RTAudio's functions are member functions of the RTAudio class. So just to confirm, JNA isn't the way to go right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What this question amounts to is asking [how to call C++ instance methods using JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873194/jna-calling-methods-upon-c-instance-passed-back-from-dll), and it's possible, but you're going to have to do some work.  In particular, you'll need to write a wrapper which `extern "C"`s any functions you actually need to invoke.

For any arbitrary `type* function()` definition you can map the method using JNA as returning a `com.sun.jna.Pointer`, but you won't be able to invoke methods on a C++ object from JNA.

A simple workaround for this would be to write a C interface library that simply invokes the method on the objects for you...so if you have some member function `foo()` you could export a C method from your C++ code:

```
extern "C" void bar(type* var){
   var->foo();
}
```

Obviously this will add some work for you...but I suspect the overhead for switching to [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) would be about the same.

JNA only cares about the way in which the method is exported in the DLL -- and that must be *without* C++ decorations (hence the `extern "C"`), so you can do whatever you need to within any such method without exposing methods that you call.

In my contrived example above, this means that `foo()`, as long as it is defined within the DLL does not in fact have to even be exposed.  Since it's a C++ function, JNA cannot call it directly, but it can be called from within a function that JNA can call, which is why my proposed solution works.

So, yes, you can fully encapsulate calls to all the member functions (create, operate, destroy) in a single function and JNA won't care.

Comment: Great answer thanks. If a regular C method creates the C++ class instance inside the function body, calls the member function, and then deletes the object, can I avoid this binding of member functions directly? Or will JNA somehow "know" and reject what otherwise appear to be C functions but that use C++ inside their bodies?

Comment: @carneades - needed more space than comments allow, see my edit in the post.

Comment: Thank you Mark, this worked perfectly!

extern "C" void rtattempt(void)
{
  RtAudio::RtAudio audio;
  std::cout << "num devices: " << audio.getDeviceCount() << std::endl;
}

Answer (score 4):

Try [Swig](http://www.swig.org/index.php). It will create wrappers for c++ classes for you.

Answer (score 3):

[BridJ](http://bridj.googlecode.com) is a spiritual child of JNA that adds some limited C++ support (+ full support from [JNAerator](http://jnaerator.googlecode.com)). If you're not using too many templates it might just work...

*(disclaimer: I'm the author of BridJ & JNAerator)*

Comment: Looked at it, not supported for 7 yrs. Try Swig, it works in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Youre right JNA is for accesing native libraries. I think what you need is a Java - COM Bridge. If this is the case there are a few free alternatives:

JCOM http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom

Jacob http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project

I've used Jacob in the pass with good results, but I think it's a little bit outdated.