# How to reuse a C code on Android without JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, c

I know, there's a lot of questions to how reuse a native code on Android.

But, it's always necessary to use JNI. And, for my app, it's a problem because I can't do any modification on my C/C++ code.

Is there a way like JNA that I can use on Android?

I'm using Eclipse and windows. If it be possibe to reuse the code like a library (.dll or .so), it will be perfect.

Comment: You may not have to modify the C/C++ code, but instead simply write additional C bridge code to allow JNI to work.

Comment: Is a JNI wrapper class that wraps your C/C++ API out of the question?

Comment: Oops, yes "wrapper" is a better term than "bridge".

Comment: When I use JNA, i don't need to do that, right? I'm looking for something like this, just java code... In the future, maybe, i'll receive a library already compiled.

Comment: Yes, JNA will usually allow you to use the native C code without a wrapper, but it doesn't handle C++ type calls without writing a wrapper for that (see [Java Native Access doesn't do C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241685/java-native-access-doesnt-do-c-right)).

Comment: But... and for pure C code? Is there a way to do on Android something like JNA?

@DeeV, sorry... how can i do this? If it's not necessary to do any modification in original C code... maybe it will work!

Comment: I've not tested JNA with Android so I cannot answer that. What does Google say on this?