# Mapping of type: char**& in JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

My client gave me dll with a couple of functions. One of them is:

```
int GetVersions(char* name, char** &pVersions);
```

It returns a number of versions for the given name and the array of strings with those versions.
Using JNA, I'm trying to write equivalent Java method in my interface:

```
int GetVersions(String name, String ll, ??? pVersions);
```

The problem is what type should be instead of `???` ?

I was trying to put there `PointerByReference` and after method invocation I had:

```
Pointer ptr = ptrRef.getValue();
String ppp = ptr.getStringarray(0);
```

but I got here `Invalid memory access`.

```
Pointer ptr = ptrRef.getValue();
String ppp = ptr.getString(0, "UTF-8");
```

returns garbage.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `getStringArray()` assumes that your string array is going to be terminated with a `NULL` pointer to indicate the end.  Is that the case here?  You might try `getStringArray()` with an explicit, limited length to see if you can just pull back the first element.

Answer (score 2):

The char ** mapping with PointerByReference.

For example:

C code:

```
char **xs_directory(struct xs_handle *h, uint32_t t,const char *path, unsigned int *num);
```

JNA:

```
PointerByReference xs_directory(XenstoreLibrary.xs_handle h, int t, String path, IntBuffer num);
```

This a xenstore api get contents of a directory,the num is PointerByReference pointer count. I use this code to get the pointer value.

```
PointerByReference pbr = XenstoreLibrary.INSTANCE.xs_directory(xs_handle, tran, "/local/domain/0", intBuffer);

int n = intBuffer.get();

Pointer[] arrays = pbr.getPointer().getPointerArray(0,n);

for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {

    Pointer array = arrays[i];

    System.out.println(array.getString(0));

}
```

sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this works in C like this:

```
char** versions; // char* versions[];
char   name [] = "some_name";

int size = GetVersions(name, &versions);
// now versions[0] to versions[size-1] are string literals of available versions
```

`char**` can be interpreted as an array of string literals (`String[]`). `char**&` is a reference to one, meaning that it can be set from inside function - and it's not available to use in pure C used by JNA (and JNI).

I'd recommend wrapping it into C-linkable code - make sure it doesn't throw exceptions, use `extern "C"` and replaces all references with pointers. E.g. something like

```
extern "C" int CGetVersions(char* name, char*** pVersions) {
    return GetVersions(name, *pVersions);
}
```

Then you should be able to use `PointerByReference` to hold `pVersions`:

```
ptrRef;                                       // (void**)
ptrRef.getValue();                            // *(void**) ->(void*)
ptrRef.getValue().getStringArray(0,returned); // (char**) (void*) -> (char**) -> String[]
```

Basically C++ works different that C, and both JNA and JNI were designed to work with C, so you have to strip down everything that you wouldn't call in plain C. Perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241685/java-native-access-doesnt-do-c-right) you can find some more information about how wrap your library with C-linkable functions.

Comment: If mangling were the issue he wouldn't have gotten as far as he did.