# How to include a library in Java which in C++ with having native binding in Java (librets)?

Tags: java, c++, makefile

I am stuck at importing a library which is originally written in C++, but has native binding for Java. Here is the library https://github.com/NationalAssociationOfRealtors/libRETS, and I was able to build it through the [doc](https://github.com/NationalAssociationOfRealtors/libRETS/blob/master/doc/build/unix.txt) in `doc/build`, but what after that? I see some makefiles in `project/build/` and I want to import this library in Java. Any help will be really appreciated as I cannot find anything in the documentation, all I know is there are some makefiles and the description claims that this library has native bindings for other languages.

Comment: You have tu use either JNA or JNI, I think you will find many answer with that keywords, like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241685/java-native-access-doesnt-do-c-right

Comment: If you look at the examples here http://www.dis.com/NAR/libRETS_Dev_Guide.html#connecting-session, I think it's being imported as a jar directly. Is there a way to make a jar out of this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the output of `./configure` carefully and make sure the build is configured to create the SWIG components (namely, for Java.)

> ```
> Option summary:
>
> Use ccache .................: no
> Use dependency checking ....: no
> Use -fPIC...................: yes
> Use shared dependencies.....: yes
> Compile type................: Normal
> Compile examples............: no
> Compile SQL compiler........: no
> Compile SWIG bindings.......: no <-------- should say yes
>   With DotNet...............: no
>   With Java.................: no <--------- me too
>   With PERL.................: no
>   With PHP..................: no
>   With Python 2.............: no
>   With Python 3.............: no
>   With Ruby.................: no
>   With Node.js..............: no
> Enable Maintainer Docs......: no
> ```

I tried it and a fairly recent version of SWIG was required -- more recent than were in my package manager. Without that, the SWIG bindings don't get built and there's no Java.

However, once you *do* get that build, it should be a fairly straightforward endeavor of calling into a `jar` file, as with any other Java project. Who knows, the build might even generate Javadoc for you so you have some idea of what to call.

Comment: Found it. Thanks mate!