# Java function accepting garbage values for variable which is returned from c++ function using JNA

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native, jna

Here i am calling **giveIntGetInt(int a)** function from JAVA .
**C++ DLL**

```
 int simpleDLL::giveIntGetInt(int a)  
          {
             int result = a *2;
            return result;
           }
```

**JAVA Method to call C++ function using JNA**

```
public class Main {
    public interface simpleDLL extends Library {

        simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "simpleDLL" : "simpleDLLLinuxPort"), simpleDLL.class);

        int giveIntGetInt(int a);       // int giveIntGetInt(int a);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("simpleDLL");
        simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;


        int a = 3;
        int result1 = sdll.giveIntGetInt(a); 
        System.out.println("giveIntGetInt("+a+"): " + result1);


    }
}
```

**Output**

> giveIntGetInt(3): 181972

Whhy am i getting a **Garbage value** when the result should be **6** ? Am i correctly mapping to the Java type to Native type ? What am i missing here ?

Thank You

Comment: Java `int` is 32 bits. C++ `int` could be anything over 16 bits. So first question are they the same size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Native Access doesn't do C++, right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241685/java-native-access-doesnt-do-c-right)

Comment: @user4581301 Yes they are of same size.

Comment: See the above duplicate post. You can't call C++ methods, although you won't get an error that they don't exist, either. The value you are seeing is a random (ok, not random, but useless to you!) pointer.  You have to export your methods to make them accessible in JNA.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I am able to call c++ methods and When i am returning a number(say 5) or variable from c++ , It will be displayed in my JAVA application but variable that is passed to c++ from java is garbage.