# How to implement functions with non standard names

Tags: java, jna

I have a dll (with source) LibUVCCam.dll that I want to implement using Java JNA. I've followed the msvcrt tutorial and it works.

Using dependency walker, I dumped the names of the functions and get things like ?listDevices@UVCCameraLibrary@@SAXPEAPEADAEAH@Z and I want to implement listDevices(). How do I define that in:

```
public interface JNALoader extends Library
{
  JNALoader INSTANCE = (JNALoader) Native.loadLibrary(("LibUVCCam"), JNALoader.class);
  ???? listDevices() // ???? = I don't know what to do here.
}
```

Here is the function from the source of the library:

```
/*
* static function
* List connected devices
* @cameraNames : (out) name list of connected cameras
* @nDevices : (out) the number of connected cameras
*/
void UVCCameraLibrary::listDevices(char **cameraNames , int &nDevices)
{
...
}
```

The full source for the project is https://github.com/sky19938470/uvcamera-windows-project/tree/master/LibUVCCam.

Comment: The library source is C++, not Java.  Also that "????" looks suspiciously like you have some problem with a different character encoding somewhere.  Does the library have a separate API you can use?  That might be easier.

Comment: I did just answer this question on the JNA Mailing list with some details.  First, the syntax (`UVCCameraLibrary::`) is C++.  You can't use that in JNA.  Look in the header files for `extern "C"` and a function prototype defined there.    Second, we need more info from the API on what is expected for the `cameraNames` variable.  The function shows it's a pointer to a memory location, but gives no information on whether you or the DLL is responsible for allocating and freeing the memory for the names.

Comment: @DanielWiddis - I did see your reply and did reply and there is no extern "C" in the header files, but I needed to go further on the structure for extern "C" as I'm not a C++ programmer. The link to the code I'm trying to implement is https://github.com/sky19938470/uvcamera-windows-project/tree/master/LibUVCCam. I'm trying to use the dll from this project. If I had an example wrapper for this dll for listDevices, I think I could figure out the rest of the calls I want to use.

Comment: @rossum - the ???? is just a place holder for "I don't know" I modified my OP.

Comment: JNA doesn't seem to provide a way to call C++ code from Java. You'll need to write a C wrapper.   Link to old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241685/java-native-access-doesnt-do-c-right  -- I'm not sure if this is still true.

Comment: @user13784117 is correct. Most cross-platform code including `libffi` that JNA leverages, uses the C API.  You have to write (and compile) a C++ program, using `extern "C"` to export your own functions to make them available for JNA, and calling the native code from inside your wrapper.  No other portable options.