# Renaming DLL functions?

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface, jna

Is there a way for me to name my exported dll functions? When I use a dll export viewer the function names shown are the full declarations. I would like to use the JNA (JNI) to access functions inside the DLL, and the function names need to be a function name not a full declaration. If this is a duplicate please point it out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Native Access doesn't do C++, right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241685/java-native-access-doesnt-do-c-right)

Comment: @DanielWiddis -- that is for C++ DLLs. OP is asking about C DLLs.

Comment: @Andy OP hasn't actually been clear on exactly what function names are shown.  In the context of JNA, the function names are identical, and "full declarations" tend to be C++.

Comment: @DanielWiddis -- I was going off of his tags.

Comment: @Andy fair enough, which is why I upvoted your answer.  For me, this is similar to other questions I've seen regarding C++ name mangling.  We both need more details to really answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can actually be done with just the __declspec(dllexport) syntax (that is, without a .def file) if you declare the function as extern "C" (or implement it in a C file instead of C++).

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall MyFunc(std::string &);
}
```

Generally much easier than exporting a mangled name with an alias (as you then need to track down the mangled name in order to assign an alias).

Comment: Doesn't that still change the export name? According to this, it would rename it to `_MyFunc`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467187/1204153

Comment: That fixed it, I just surrounded all the exported functinos with "externc "C"" and it works. Could you explain what that does?

Comment: @lucas.ss.05 JNA uses FFI, which requires a C API.  It cannot directly access C++ functions. The syntax in this answer is how you can provide a C API in a C++ DLL.

Comment: I meant to mention that, its C im coding in