# Catch a "double" hotkey

Tags: java, swing, scala, hotkeys

I have to catch a hotkey of `Ctrl+Alt+C, C` (meaning, press `Ctrl+Alt+C`, release only `C` and press it again). Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
import com.tulskiy.keymaster.common._
import java.awt.event._
import javax.swing.KeyStroke

class KeysCatcher {

  val provider = Provider.getCurrentProvider(true)
  val ctrlC = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK + ActionEvent.ALT_MASK)

  val listener = new HotKeyListener() {
    def onHotKey(hotKey: HotKey): Unit = {
      hotKey.keyStroke match {
        case `ctrlC` =>
          println("Ctrl+Alt+C 1 was pressed")

          val listener2 = new HotKeyListener() {
            def onHotKey(hotKey: HotKey): Unit = {
              hotKey.keyStroke match {
                case `ctrlC` => println("Ctrl+Alt+C 2 was pressed")
              }
            }
          }

          provider.register(ctrlC, listener2)
      }
    }
  }

  provider.register(ctrlC, listener)
}
```

I had the idea that once `Ctrl+Alt+C` is pressed I have to register the same hotkey again and catch it. I was going to involve a timer since the second press of `C` should be pretty quick. But I think I took the wrong way since it would make pretty complicated.

Your thoughts? 
P.S. There is no window there, it catches a **global** hotkey. I've also tried much stuff from the Internet and it didn't work as I wanted, so before providing me any code please test it.

Although this example is Scala, Java would be ok also.

Dependency:

```
https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster

//build.scala
val jkeymaster = "com.github.tulskiy" % "jkeymaster" % "1.1"
```

Comment: `com.tulskiy....` what is that supposed to be? can you make a self contained example using only Scala Swing?

Comment: @0__, sorry I forgot about it. I can't use only Swing.

Comment: @0__, the thing is that `KeyStroke` is a Swing class.

Comment: Your chances of getting help is a lot higher if one can execute your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a global hotkey only once, but you can receive its events in the handler many times. So the basic idea is to save the last time your saw this key and if two are coming between certain delay, you have a double click:

```scala
    var last = 0l
    val listener = new HotKeyListener() {
      def onHotKey(hotKey: HotKey): Unit = {
        hotKey.keyStroke match {
          case `ctrlC` =>
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - last < 700) // arbitrary delay of 700 ms
              println("We have a double click!")
            else last = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
      }
    }
```

if you want something without var, I guess you can wrap it in a `Promise` or something.

Comment: It works, however, there is another issue appeared. When I can Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V nothing is pasted from clipboard which means nothing is copied there either. I wonder why? I'd like it not to shadow system clipboard, that is to say, whenever I press Ctrl+C (or Ctrl+C, C) the text should be copied to clipboard. Or at least I'd like to control this. Now I have no control on that.

Comment: In other words, it seems it doesn't allow a hotkey to propagate further.

Comment: @Alex: in this case you'd probably need to use a keyboard hook like https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

Comment: isn't your library able to propogate a hotkey?

Comment: @Alex: my library is only doing system calls for registering global hotkeys, I can't do much beyond that. If the OS decides that a global hotkey has higher precedence than application-specific hotkeys, then so be it. And it seems to be the case with both linux and windows.