# What to wrap in a C/C++ project into Java by JNI or JNA?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, wrapper

I'm a Java developer.

I have a source code of a project in C/C++, which has an interface in C.

I need to wrap it into Java. I guess I'll use JNI (**Edit** : or JNA would be used).

My question is :

What is the "wrappable" part? Should I wrap source code or the compiled version?

For the fact that I need to **access to the interface (*.h)**, should I wrap :

- *.DLL
- *.LIB
- *.h

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at Java Native Access instead? It may be more suitable. Regarding what to wrap, it depends on the particulars, but usually you'd make the Java API a client of the C shared library (DLL) just like any other program that uses it.

Comment: You need both .h (to code your JNI Library against) and the DLL at runtime.

Comment: Thank you both (@chrylis + @Gyro) for your answers. Would it be the same in case of using JNA as suggested by @chrylis ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556421/use-jni-instead-of-jna-to-call-native-code