# How to access .net dll from TIBCO BusinessWorks

Tags: .net, tibco, businessworks

Currently I'm working in TIBCO Business Works. I need some clarification related to dot net and TIBCO BusinessWorks communication. Other than Webservice cosuming option, is that any other options (or adapters) are available to connect dll file from TIBCO BusinessWorks?

Answer (score 0):

1 - If you use WCF internally, this exists : https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-ems-transport-channel-for-wcf-2-0-0

2 - There are also ways to assemble .Net and BusinessWorks Implementation types in service grid... but this REQUIRES service definition on each end (WCF on the .Net end + WSDL)... and having a Service Grid wrapper just for that is overkill. 
There are no ".Net" or "dll" palette inside BusinessWorks, to my knowledge (BW has Java roots)

3 - So it sounds like you will have to integrate with Web Services, Messages (a MOM that support .Net and Java, like EMS), Databases (any DBMS) or files... Sometimes the simplest ways are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Since BW is Java-based other another possible approach might be using JNA or JNI in a Java Code activity.

There is a great discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556421/use-jni-instead-of-jna-to-call-native-code) on the merits of JNA versus JNI.