# DLL library errors when using functions in multiple files

Tags: c++

I am making libraries, to use in multiple games so I don't have to duplicate code. In this example, my main program is `main.cpp` and the other two files are my libraries. Everything is linked correctly.

When all my functions in `Common Functions Library.h` have `static` in front, I get the error: `static function 'std::string common::joinAll(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>)' declared but not defined (Error C2129)` from `main.cpp` (even though the functions are in the `Common Functions Library.h/.cpp`), and it says the line number is one more than there is in the whole program which is very strange.

So, to fix this, I found people online saying I need to replace `static` with `inline`, so I tried again and got this error: `cannot open file 'Common Functions Library.lib' (Error LNK1104)`

Then I tried setting all the functions back to `static`, and then commented out `#include "Cubes Library.h"` in `main.cpp`, which didn't give me the other errors anymore, but instead things related to the cubes library (obviously). However, this stopped on line 65, after where the functions which caused the errors saying they weren't defined. I have no clue what is going wrong, but thanks for any help :)

`Code:`

> main.cpp

```
#include "Common Functions Library.h"
#include "Cubes Library.h"

// Using functions from `Common Functions Library`
```

> Common Functions Library.cpp (Part of a DLL)

```
#include "Common Functions Library.h"


namespace common
{
    // Functions
}
```

> Cubes Library.cpp (Part of a DLL)

```
#include "Cubes Library.h"
#include "Common Functions Library.h"
```

Comment: Read about exporting static exporting static function here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984316/dll-export-of-a-static-function

Comment: If you make function inline, you can place its body inside the header file, so you don't have to put it inside your DLL.

Comment: @WindyFields Both DLL's are made up of a header file and source file - so what shall I do? I read the SO forum, but I am still not sure

Comment: @WindyFields I have put all my functions in the header file, but it still says that it cannot open the .lib file ):

Comment: Because "cannot open file 'Common Functions Library.lib' (Error LNK1104)" probably has nothing to do with your functions.

Comment: "Common Functions Library" is in dynamic library (DLL according to your words) but you try to reference it as a static library - linker is angry.

Comment: @WindyFields I followed the Microsoft guide - what bit did I do wrong?

Comment: If you did everything according to *the guide* I see no way you could get such a message. And if you follow the guide, then **follow the guide**, don't make anything inline - it's a different technique.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: @WindyFields Yeah it did work with one file, but not multiple files - I'll figure it out soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `inline` in front of all functions and define in header, there is no need for `.cpp` file and hence no need for `.lib`.

I also see `namespace common` in your `Common Functions Library.h`. So don't forget to put `using namespace common;` in your `main.cpp` or prefix `common::` before all usage of class in `main.cpp`.